# Cassandra 2.2.3 Java Requirements

Tags: cassandra

Does anyone know if Cassandra 2.2.3 supports Oracle Java 8? Is there a place where we can go to see supported Java versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of a table or location that lists a cross-reference of all Cassandra versions and the Java versions that they support.  But the [Cassandra 2.2 installation documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/install/installTarball.html) has this information:

> **Prerequisites**
>
> - Latest version of Oracle Java Platform, Standard Edition 8 (JDK) or OpenJDK 7.

That can change with the version of Cassandra that you are installing.  The [Cassandra 2.1 installation doc](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/install/installTarball_t.html) also adds:

> Note: It is recommended to use the latest version of Oracle Java 8 on all nodes. (Oracle Java 7 is also supported.)